# Most "react" way to have multiple different renderings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope this question isn't too subjective. I've been doing a lot of React development lately, and I have a header that used to have two different renderings.

Recently my client has asked for two additional renderings. I could nest conditionals in the renderings, but this feels messy to me and against good practices.

For example I have this:

```
{this.state.headerLoc ? (
  <div className="secondary-nav">
   ...
   </div>
  ) : (
  <Back />
  )}
```

I'd like to add two additional conditions to this - is there a "clean" way to do this without a bunch of additional nesting? Would refactoring/subcomponents be the only way to handle this condition?

EDIT: Pseudo-code example of what I want to do:

```
render {
  if(page == 'page1') {
    <renderX />
  }
  else if(page == 'page2') {
    <renderX2 />
  }
  else if(page == 'page3') {
    <renderX3 />
  }
  else if(page == 'page4') {
    <renderX4 />
  }
}
```

EDIT: Update for what I am doing now:

```
const HeaderArrays = {
  FrontPage: ["/"],
  SearchPage: ["cards", "map", "detail"],
  NonSearchPage:[],
  NonSearchPageHamburger:["settings"],
}

HeaderComponents() {
  var routerPath = this.props.router.location.pathname;
  for (const component in HeaderArrays) {
    const value = HeaderArrays[component];
    if(HeaderArrays[component].includes(routerPath)) {
      return component;
    }
   return "FrontPage";
 }

render() {

  const ComponentToRender = this.HeaderComponents();
  return(
    <ComponentToRender />
```

Comment: Sounds like you already know what the best practice is. Breaking it down into functional components will make it much easier to work with. e.g. `const SecondaryNav = (props) => { ... }`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that's probably what the best practices would be, but wasn't totally sure as I'm new to React and wasn't sure if there was a better type of design for the logic

Comment: Is there anyway to replicate an if/else if/else if block in rendering? Or am I thinking in an anti-pattern here?

Comment: Could you expand the example in your question to explain what you mean?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: React is just a JavaScript lib, you're not required to use JSX everywhere, and you can do anything in JSX that you can in JS.

Comment: Your psuedocode is already good enough. Don't overthink things too much! The only thing I'd do to improve the readability is change it to a `switch` statement

Comment: You can do what your pseudo code does, just add a `return`. Though it would be best to just build a whole new page component for each page and use some kind of router if you don't have one already.

Comment: Well this is for a header that was originally supposed to have one main form, and an alternative form for the front page. It has had two conditions added to it.

Comment: Also I get the message, "expression expected" when I am trying to use it in the return method in my IDE. That's why I felt it wouldn't work...

Comment: Why not just map with an object to type? `{page4: Page4Component}`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I’m not exactly familiar with that approach - could you put it in an answer?

Comment: Perfect question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just map components to a key in an object. this way you can omit a bunch of if else statements

```
const HeaderComponents = {
  page1: Page1HeaderComponent,
  page2: Page2HeaderComponent,
  page3: Page3HeaderComponent,
  page4: Page4HeaderComponent
}
```

and usage would be

```
render() {
  const { page } = this.props // assuming page comes from props
  const ComponentToRender = HeaderComponents[page]
  return <ComponentToRender />
}
```

[**Here's an example to play with :)**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1wtph)

Comment: Oh awesome, this is a LOT cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Yea, anytime I have more than 2 conditionals I usually just map elements this way. Its a lot more explicit and more readable + helps a ton when dealing with dynamic data sets as well :)

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Just a question - can they be class components? Or do they have to be dumb? Because I am trying a variation of this, and getting the error: "<FrontPage /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements."

Comment: Yes it can be any class or functional component. Just a mapping. If you wanna update what issue you're experiencing in your question. Or a codesandbox I can fix it :)

Comment: @AndrewAlexander heres an example with classes and functions :) https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-1wtph

Comment: I added what I was trying to do. I'm basically checking if my path is in one of the array in my object and then assigning that to the component to be rendered, when I have my error.

Comment: Why are you returning "FrontPage" like that? shouldn't it be the actual component? And what is `HeaderArrays`

Comment: Sorry, I included HeaderArrays - it's basically a list of all the paths that are associated with a given component. And I am returning "FrontPage" like that as the default. And I'm not entirely sure - wouldn't I want to pass a string and then put it into a component? Sorry if I am misunderstanding what I should be doing here. I was just trying to provide a default so there wasn't a null value

Comment: Dont be sorry :) sometimes my questions are direct, not intended to come off as hard. What I mean is in my answer the mapping happens between a name and the actual component reference. You should be returning the actual component

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. Is there anyway to make a mapping between my object keys and the components if they're the same? I will obviously change the default to just the component name

Comment: @AndrewAlexander the arrays you're pointing to a header name, is that coming from the pathname? aka `NonSearchPageHamburger:["settings"],` is `settings` from the path like `/settings`?

Comment: Yeah I'm grabbing it as such: var routerPath = this.props.router.location.pathname;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196891/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-andrew-alexander).